# Por que aparece basura al borrar un nodo de ABB (C++)

Tags: c++

Estoy realizando un árbol abb  pero tengo el problema que al momento de borrar el nodo deja basura y tengo entendido que al borrar el nodo debería de borra la información Esto paso desde que le agregue cadena de caracteres

==========================

struct Nodo{

```
int dato;
int calificacion;
char Nombre[30];
char Apellido[30];
Nodo *der;
Nodo *izq;
Nodo *padre;
```

};

```
Nodo *crearNodo(int n,int c,char *nom,char *Apell, Nodo *padre)
```

{

```
Nodo *nuevo_nodo = new Nodo();

nuevo_nodo -> dato = n;
nuevo_nodo ->calificacion= c;
strcpy(nuevo_nodo ->Nombre,nom);
strcpy(nuevo_nodo ->Apellido,Apell);
nuevo_nodo->der = NULL;
nuevo_nodo->izq = NULL;
nuevo_nodo->padre = padre;
    
return nuevo_nodo;
```

}

```
void eliminar(Nodo *arbol,int n){
    
if(arbol == NULL){
return;
}

else if (n < arbol->dato){
    eliminar(arbol->izq,n);
}   



else if(n > arbol->dato){
     eliminar(arbol->der,n);

}

else{
 
 delete  arbol;

}
```

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Cuando lo borro aparece esto **

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`al borrar el nodo debería de borra la información`

Falso. No toca la memoria; solo hace que quede disponible para si vuelves a reservar (con `new` o `malloc`).

Pero la cuestión importante es que *el nodo padre no sabe que la memoria se ha liberado*. El sigue teniendo un puntero que apunta a una dirección de memoria que parece válida (no es *NULL*), así que cuando vuelvas a recorrer el árbol intentará acceder a esa posición de memoria y trabajar con lo que haya allí.

Tomando como base lo que tienes, haría que:

- *eliminar* devuelve un bool, que será *true* inmediatamente después de hacer el *delete* y *false* en caso contrario.
- Si una llamada a *eliminar* devuelve *true*, en el nodo padre asignarás *NULL* al puntero al nodo eliminado.

Comment: En [tag:c++] no debería usarse `malloc`.